# Hebrew language in Ubuntu 16.04.4

Tags: xfce, locale, thunar, encoding, hebrew

I'm using 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-119-generic x86_64) with Xfce.

I have Hebrew folder names that are shown with invalid encoding:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: You should be able to solve your problem by following this guide to setting up Hebrew locale: [HebrewLocalizationHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HebrewLocalizationHowto) Shalom!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Does this appear on all file systems or only Windows file systems and external media (i. e. FAT and NTFS)? Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `locale`, `grep -e '^/dev/' /proc/mounts` and `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX dpkg -l culmus xfonts-efont-unicode xfonts-efont-unicode-ib xfonts-intl-european ttf-mscorefonts-installer 2>/dev/null`? Thanks.